# Change Matplotlib's Coordinate

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates

matplotlib has its own local coordinate. 
However, I would like to change it to my own lat and lon data. The data has  its max and min latitude and longitude as a list, so the only thing needs to be done is to replace the range of x and y axis.
Is this possible for me to do that?

```
{'minLat': 109.0, 'maxLat': 177.7, 'maxLong': 177.64, 'minLong': 131.8}
```

this is the lat and lon that needs to replace the x and y coordinates. This list is generated through my defined function.

Comment: I am not pretty sure about your question.  You want to set the axis of your graph, or set the xlim and ylim?

Answer (score 0):

Using `set_xlim()` and `set_ylim()` allows us to change the axis limits.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
coord = {'minLat': 109.0, 'maxLat': 177.7, 'maxLong': 177.64, 'minLong': 131.8}
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim((coord["minLong"], coord["maxLong"]))
ax.set_ylim((coord["minLat"], coord["maxLat"]))
ax.plot( some values )
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried this before. But the problem is that the axis indeed shows the right thing but the coordinate it returns once clicked on certain spot is still the original local matplotlib coordinate instead of my lat&long coordinates

Comment: I just verified. I think ax.set_xlim is only tell matplotlib to move the plotting area to another specified place. But the thing is that i need my graph still in the center of the picture but the returning coordinates of the point needs to correlate to the new lat&long coordinates.

Comment: When plotting in matplotlib, we only care about data corrdinates (all other coordinates like figure coordinates may be relevant for placing axes, legends etc. but not for plotting). There is no such thing as "local coordinates". I would suggest you provide a [mcve] of the issue (not more than 10 lines) and then we will find a solution.